# Why is adding to a static ArrayList in a constructor a leak?

Tags: java, constructor, arraylist

I am using the NetBeans IDE and it is giving me a warning that does not make sense to me.  The warning states "Leaking this in constructor".  The following code is the basic setup (I just removed code irrelevant to the issue). Basically I just want to keep a list of all `Square` objects made.  Is this a warning I need to worry about?  Or is it just the possible cause of a memory leak depending on the situation?

Either way, can someone explain why this would be considered a leak?

```
public class Square {
    private static ArrayList<Square> squares;

    public Square() {
        if(squares == null) {
            squares = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        squares.add(this); // I get a warning on this line
    }
}
```

I know it is just a warning, but I don't like to ignore warnings unless I fully understand what is going on and can make the informed choice for a specific situation.

Thanks!

Comment: cant you just do  `private static ArrayList<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();`

Comment: Is your objective really to maintain a list of all created squares at runtime? If yes, there is a better way to achieve that

Comment: "Leak" here is not a memory leak, although you arguably also have that problem. It's that you're letting `this` escape from a constructor.

Comment: Thank you @SeanOwen I did not think of that either, but it certainly makes sense and helped me understand what is happening here.

Comment: @KayoticSully also have a look at my answer if my guess was correct. Note that if you make `newSquare()` synchronized, you also add thread safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the warning concerns garbage collection, although that is indeed a problem here. The instances will never be GC'ed (unless the whole `ClassLoader` is collected).

The warning is saying that `this` is being passed to another method from within the constructor. Before the constructor finishes, `this` is not necessarily a fully-formed and initialized object according to the logic enshrined in the constructor. Anything in the constructor is intended to happen before anything else gets its hands on the object. But something else is getting to use `this` before the constructor finishes. That could cause surprising bugs.

Answer (score 4):

(not really an answer, but...)

If your objective is really to maintain, in a list, the list of all squares you create, there is a better way to achieve that:

```
public class Square
{
    private static final List<Square> allSquares = new ArrayList<Square>();

    // Constructor: private!
    private Square() {}

    // Create a square
    public static Square newSquare()
    {
        Square ret = new Square();
        allSquares.add(ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

You will note that there is no `this` escape in the constructor.

For creating a new square, you will then do:

```
Square mySquare = Square.newSquare();
```

Comment: +1 because actually this is exactly what would avoid what the IDE is warning about.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Not something I asked for, but definitely a solution I could use!

Answer (score 2):

> can someone explain why this would be considered a leak?

It is a (potential) leak because the `squares` list and any object in the list won't be garbage collected.  If there is no other code to either remove objects from the list, or clear or null the list, then objects will leak via the list.

---

Perhaps you need to understand what "memory leak" means in the context of a garbage collected language.  In a language like C or C++, a storage leak happens when objects are lost; i.e. the code that should have free / disposed the object fails to do so.  In an garbage collected language, a leak occurs when the GC fails to free / dispose an object because it appears to still be in use; i.e. the GC can still find the object by tracing.

---

However on rereading the question, I agree with Sean Owen.  The message "Leaking this in constructor" is most likely talking about the fact that the constructor is making the object's reference visible before the constructor has completed.  This is also referred to as "unsafe publication".  It can be a source of insidious concurrency bugs.  (It could even be a problem in a single-threaded application; e.g. if you create a subclass of Square ...)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I just need to be good about removing objects from the ArrayList when they are not needed anymore. Maybe not a good practice, but it should suffice for what I need.  I'll start thinking of a better possible solution to my problem then.  Thanks!

Comment: This is all true, but it is not what the IDE is warning about.

Comment: @KayoticSully - *"I just need to be good about removing objects from the ArrayList when they are not needed anymore."*  That can be tricky ... because it can be difficult to figure out when the object is not needed any more.

Comment: @StephenC Absolutely, I do need to come up with something better to do what I need.  This was just the first thing that came to mind so I wanted to try it out and was confused by the warning.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: this is just a guess!*

If this is the only place that `squares` is modified, then it means that `Square` objects can never be garbage-collected, as there'll always be at least one reference to each object.  If so, perhaps your IDE is smart enough to spot this.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is adding to a static ArrayList in a constructor a memory leak?

Nope. That's not the root cause of the warning you are getting. However there are multiple other problems.

1. `this` should not be passed outside the constructor. (sporadic issues can arise if you don't follow this)
2. `Square` class holds a list of all it's objects created. That means for each object created there exists at least on reference.

   ```
   Square aSq = new Square(); // two references, aSq and reference in ArrayList
   new Square(); // one reference in ArrayList
   ```

   So, until the class is present in memory, all the objects created will never be Garbage Colleced. and hence memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you understand that static variables are referenced by Class objects which are referenced by ClassLoaders. So unless your ClassLoader itself qualifies for garbage collection , or the ClassLoader drops your referencing Class by some means, it will never be garbage collected. So, everytime your constructor is called , you are adding data to a list that will almost never gets garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, I think this is a bad practice.

The raison d'etre for OOP, is encapsulation of a set of contracts. And those contracts must be clearly visible to the subscriber of the class.

When someone instantiates `new Square()`, it would not be obvious to the programmer that the instantiation is also adding this instance into a non-garbage-collected list.

So, I the programmer happily instantiate Square frequently and trivially believing that it would be garbage collected as long as I consciously abrogate all references to each of those trivially instantiated Squares. But I am wrong - because despite all my conscious efforts, none of the instances would be garbage collected.

You know, garbage collection has afforded us programmers some habitual short-cut practices. For example, the following while structure exemplifies a simplification of trivially instantiated objects. The programmer has no qualms repeatedly reinstantiating String ins, because he/she knows the previous instance would be garbage collected.

```
String ins = new String();
while(c != null && ins != null) {
  ins = new String();
  readInputInto(ins);
}
```

However, replace String with your Square and put it into the hands of the common programmer. The programmer would assume the same garbage-collectability as String!

Therefore, it is not good practice to try to do too much in your constructor, especially hiding an action that has significant impact inside the constructor.

You should simply have the instance added to the list outside the constructor.